# Изменил utf-8 на utf-16 потом обратно utf-8 вручную в activity_main.xml в строке <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> Появились ошибки. Как решить?

Tags: utf-8

Очень долго мучался как изменить кодировку чтобы в приложении вместо знаков вопросов изображался русский язык. Так и не решил проблему. Перебором случайных значений изменил в activity_main.xml значение utf-8 в первой строки

> на utf-16

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

По прежнему остались знаки вопросов вместо русского языка. Поэтому решил поставить обратно на utf-8

> 

и тут приложение перестало запускаться с множественными ошибками
[image: Ошибки после смены utf-8 на utf-16 и обратно на utf-8]

Как решить проблему?

Сам код не вижу смысла выкидывать потому что даже в пустом проекте Android Studio. Если проделать такую операцию то будут ошибки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Исходники нужно в виде текста публиковать.

Comment: Сохранить все файлы в той кодировке которая указана в заголовках